# What the difference between "RAILS_ENV=production rails c" and "rails c -e production"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-console

I used to think I could just ssh to my server, change directory and run

```
rails c -e production
```

It would then prompt me

```
Loading production environment (Rails 4.1.2)
2.1.0 :001 >
```

Production environment I would think

But when I made a query in the console I get an access denied message from the mySql.

Then I tried starting the console like this

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails c
```

Get the same prompt and my queries all work.

What the purpose of the first statement then?

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference unless you have code inside your app that uses `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` instead of calling `Rails.env` to figure out what environment it has loaded.

Comment: I only found one instance of ENV['RAILS_ENV']. And it is a setter in the test_helper.rb. But this would not explain why wrong settings get loaded when calling rails c -e production, would it?

Comment: There's probably something else that's also relying on this at your app, a gem or something like that.